# PHP Array and self math

Tags: php, arrays, math

My question is how to do a comparison function on an array of integers in PHP?

Specifically, I start with an array I want to filter:

```
$array = array(1,10,18,29,42,50,61);
```

and return an array that looks like this:

```
//return where diff > 10
$new_array = array(1,29,42,61);
```

I'm trying to ensure that I filter out any numbers where the difference is less than 10, including any adjacent numbers (hence why 18 is not in the list).

Comment: How do you calculate the difference?

Comment: That's my question, how to setup function/loop...

Comment: What kind of difference do you mean? From the next/previous element? Should be a matter of a simple `for()`, I don't see the problem to be honest

Comment: Yes, but I would want to exclude 18 too since [1,10,18] would be considered a single group (not enough of a threshold had been passed).

Comment: Let's start with explaining what those numbers mean and what the expected outcome means. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I'm doing video scene change detection. My avisynth script outputs false positives as far as frame numbers where scenes change (to a text file). I want to filter out those false positives.

Comment: And doesn't [42, 50, 60] form a group as well? So why [..., 42, 60] but not [1, 18, ...] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A greedy approximation gives you this:

```
$array = array(1,10,18,29,42,50,61);
$clusters = [];
$prev = null;

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($prev == null || $prev + 10 < $value) {
        $clusters[] = $value; // more than 10 difference between previous
    }
    $prev = $value; // update previous
}
```

It yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 29
    [2] => 42
    [3] => 61
)
```